# Using mysql results in a different page PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I would like to use mysql results generated in php file in another html file with php tags.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))    {
  echo $row['chapter'] . " " . $row['chapter_name'] ;
  echo "<br />";
}
```

the above code is in file test.php, is there a way to use this output in index.html with php tags.

I know I can add the HTML code within the test.php and finish the job but I dont users to see test.php extension in the browser.

Comment: store it in a variable and then use that variable on your other page. also, unless you have associated .html with PHP, good luck sticking PHP in it :p

Comment: 1. you can not use PHP code in .HTML file -> make all files .php and write out html inside your code. 2. you can modify on webserver the extensions, that .html file behaves like php file, its just a mask. 3. ask proper questions, 'I dont users... ' what u dont users?

Comment: In general you cannot run PHP code in HTML files, and you shouldn't. So, rename it to .php

Comment: did u consider using sessions ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use
[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
An example

```
<?php
// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./test.php', true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./test.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

Or you could use the

```
include('test.php');
```

OR

```
require('test.php');
```

Comment: @dcode `file_get_contents` is used when you want to read a file as a `string` and use its data. How is this the correct answer to your question when you just ask how to use generated data by an PHP file? It is like killing a fly with a panzer

Comment: I should have wrote
$file = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/test.php');
it was a mistake(i somehow could use the file_get_contents just for the generated html and not for the whole php code)

Answer (score 4):

First change **index.html** to **index.php**

In test.php file do:

```
$output = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))    {
  $output .= $row['chapter'] . " " . $row['chapter_name'] ;
  $output .= "<br />";
}
```

In index.php file do:

```
require "test.php";
echo $output;
```

Also please consider to use **PDO** for database access

Ref: [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Answer (score -1):

For that, u just go with `OOPS concepts`.

In `test.php`,

You just Create a Class, and add function for your fetch results.

and `result.php`

call those member function through create a object for that `class`